# Python 3 OOP - How to get names by first letter from an attribute list (Object Instance)

Tags: list, oop, search, python-3.7

guys! I have a class ('Student') with 3 attributes ('name', 'id', 'gpa'). Then I have a list ('students') of objects of that class. I need to save to another list all instances of 'students' based on the first letter ('key') of its attribute list 'name'. So the new list should have 'students.name', 'students.id', 'students.gpa' for each 'name' that starts with the 'key'.

I have tried `studentsNames = filter(lambda x: x.startswith(key), students)` But the list ('studentsNames') comes up empty, even though there are names starting with the 'key'.

This is a sample of the code. Full class Student is here:https://github.com/lelecarabina/python3/blob/master/Student.py and full code below is here: https://github.com/lelecarabina/python3/blob/master/StudentFinder.py

...

```
#Create new Student object students
students = [Student((),(),())] * numStudents

print("All Students:")

# Initialize List of Student 'students' with **CONSTRUCTOR** and Print 
for x in range(numStudents): 
    students[x] = (Student(names[x], (1101 + x), (gpas[rand]))) # constructor
    print(students[x].getName(), students[x].getId(), students[x].getGpa())

#prompt user for input
key = input("\nEnter the first letter of student's name: ")

for x in range(len(students)):
    studentsNames = [item for item in students if students[x].name[0] == key]   
    #print(studentsNames)

#print sorted list header
print("Students names starting with '{}'".format(key.upper()))    

#loop through sorted list
for x in range(numStudents): 
    #end loop if no student's names matches user's input
    if studentsNames == "": 
        print("NOT FOUND")
        break
    # end if statement

    #print sorted list is student's name matches user's input, along with name's id and gpa
    for name in studentsNames:  
        if name == students[x].name:
            print("     Name: {} -> ID: {} -> GPA: {}".format(students[x].name, students[x].id, students[x].gpa))

        # end if statement            
    # end for each loop            
# end for loop

#message to user, ending program
print("Program Ended.")
```

It should print:
     Name: ... -> ID: ... -> GPA: ... where dots are the info pulled from 'students'.
But it prints: 
"Students names starting with 'L'
Program Ended."

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I. Figured. It. Out. 
I needed `students[x].name[0] == key.upper()` instead of just `students[x].name[0] == key` because all names in the list start with capitals... 
:(

Final code snippet:
`#prompt user for input
    key = input("\nEnter the first letter of student's name: ")

```
#look for key in students.name list...
for x in range(len(students)):
    #if key found...
    if students[x].name[0] == key.upper(): 
        #add student record to studentsNames list...
        studentsNames.append(students[x].name)               

#loop through sorted list
print("Students names starting with '{}'".format(key.upper()))
for x in range(numStudents): 
    #end loop if no student's names matches key
    if studentsNames == "": 
        print("NOT FOUND")
        break
    # end if statement

    #print student records that matched key
    for name in studentsNames:  
        if name == students[x].name:
            print("     Name: {} -> ID: {} -> GPA: {}".format(students[x].name, students[x].id, students[x].gpa))    
        # end if statement            
    # end for each loop            
# end for loop`
```